# Can polynomial $p(x)$ have integer roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients can be represented like this: $p(x) = (x - x_1)(x - x_2)(x - x_3)q(x) + 1$ where $q(x)$ is some polynomial with integer coefficients and $x_1, x_2, x_3$ - different whole numbers. Can $p(x)$ have integer roots?

My observations:
$$
p(x_1) = p(x_2) = p(x_3) = 1
$$

Also $p(x) = 1$ for any $x$ - root of $q(x)$.

Assuming $p(x_0) = 0$:
$$
q(x_0) = -\frac{1}{(x_0 - x_1)(x_0 - x_2)(x_0 - x_3)}
$$

I'm not really sure what to do next. Is Vieta's Formula useful here?

Could somebody please give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible that $p$ has *only* integer roots, or if $p$ could have one or more integer roots?

Comment: @EliJohnson In my task I'm just asked if it can have integer roots... I am not sure what exactly is meant by that... I think it is likely the second option.

Comment: Suppose that $x_0$ is an integer such that $p(x_0)=0$. Note that $q(x_0)\in\mathbb Z$ since $q(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. But this is not possible by the form of $q(x_0)$ (it is the inverse of some non-unitary integer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there!

Continuing from where you left off, from the equation
$$
q(x_0) = -\frac{1}{(x_0 - x_1)(x_0 - x_2)(x_0 - x_3)}
$$
it follows that
$$
-\frac{1}{(x_0 - x_1)(x_0 - x_2)(x_0 - x_3)}
$$
is an integer, hence
$$
(x_0 - x_1)(x_0 - x_2)(x_0 - x_3)\in\{\pm 1\}
$$
but then
$$
x_0 - x_1,x_0 - x_2,x_0 - x_3\in\{\pm 1\}
$$
contradiction, since the distinctness of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ implies the distinctness of
$x_0 - x_1,x_0 - x_2,x_0 - x_3$.